# Trying to write hexadecimal value into a string in C#

Tags: c#

I need to write a hexadecimal value into a string.

I'm using this:

```
int value;
long item = Convert.ToInt64(value); // this convert value to a hexadecimal
```

So I need to write this hexadecimal value into a string...
so, when I use `ToString()`, it's convert again into integer, I need to write hexadecimal value.

Comment: what do you mean by hexadecimal value? like this "D1CE"?

Comment: You're not converting anything to hex in the code you've shown, you're converting it to a `long`. Try `string hex = value.ToString("x");`

Comment: Just to clarify the difference - Convert class changes `value`'s type to `long` (like widening cast would do), while you might want to print the actual value to the string using base 16 formatter (instead of default base 10 formatter that `Int.toString()` uses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question, but you may want to try this:

```
int value;
string s = value.ToString("X");  // int to hexadecimal string
```

If you want to reparse it back to a long:

```
ulong ul = ulong.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);  // hexadecimal string to unsigned int
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int myInt = 1243;
string myHex = myInt.ToString("X");  // gives you hex
int myNewInt = Convert.ToInt32(myHex, 16);  // back to int again.
```